# Wildfly datasource services missing

Tags: java, service, binding, jboss, wildfly

I found in other threads others having a problem similar to mine but none of the solutions worked for me.

I'm migrating from jBoss 5 to Wildfly 18. I followed the official guide to migrate.

I set up the datasources in the standalone.xml file, and they are correctly connected (the admin console test - localhost:9990 - confirms that the connections to the DB are up and running).

Anyway, I got some errors while deploying my application.

It seems that there is something wrong with the services that are supposed to use the datasources and the connections.

Can anyone please take a look at the error log here below? Is anything familiar for anyone?

I cannot figure it out ...

Thanks in advance

```
17:16:47,804 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.9.1.Final
17:16:48,855 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.4.11.Final
17:16:48,863 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 2.3.3.Final
17:16:48,940 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 18.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 10.0.3.Final) starting
17:16:49,818 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.10.4.Final
17:16:51,270 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
17:16:51,284 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
17:16:51,544 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found myApplication.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called myApplication.war.dodeploy
17:16:51,565 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
17:16:51,579 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-8) XNIO version 3.7.3.Final
17:16:51,585 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-8) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.7.3.Final
17:16:51,612 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) WFLYTX0013: The node-identifier attribute on the /subsystem=transactions is set to the default value. This is a danger for environments running multiple servers. Please make sure the attribute value is unique.
17:16:51,618 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
17:16:51,626 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.opentracing] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) WFLYTRACEXT0001: Activating MicroProfile OpenTracing Subsystem
17:16:51,626 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.config.smallrye._private] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYCONF0001: Activating WildFly MicroProfile Config Subsystem
17:16:51,632 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
17:16:51,633 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
17:16:51,637 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
17:16:51,643 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=5.0.3.Final
17:16:51,646 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.health.smallrye] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) WFLYHEALTH0001: Activating Eclipse MicroProfile Health Subsystem
17:16:51,651 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
17:16:51,652 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.metrics.smallrye] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYMETRICS0001: Activating Eclipse MicroProfile Metrics Subsystem
17:16:51,653 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.4.17.Final)
17:16:51,687 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 2.0.27.Final starting
17:16:51,738 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
17:16:51,759 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
17:16:51,812 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 43) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (version 6.4)
17:16:51,815 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 73) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path 'SERVER_PATH\wildfly-18.0.1.Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
17:16:51,819 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = sqlserver
17:16:51,985 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 24 core threads with 192 task threads based on your 12 available processors
17:16:51,989 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 48 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
17:16:51,989 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 192 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
17:16:52,007 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYRS0016: RESTEasy version 3.9.1.Final
17:16:52,010 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBoss Remoting version 5.0.15.Final
17:16:52,014 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
17:16:52,016 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
17:16:52,045 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
17:16:52,263 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete
17:16:52,290 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.AbstractDataSourceService$AS7DataSourceDeployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) IJ020018: Enabling <validate-on-match> for java:jboss/datasources/datasource1
17:16:52,290 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.AbstractDataSourceService$AS7DataSourceDeployer] (MSC service thread 1-8) IJ020018: Enabling <validate-on-match> for java:jboss/datasources/datasource2

...
other datasources enabled
...


17:16:52,354 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/datasource1]
17:16:52,354 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/datasource2]

...
other datasources bind
...


17:16:53,791 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYPAT0050: WildFly Full cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none
17:16:53,798 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYDM0111: Keystore SERVER_PATH\wildfly-18.0.1.Final\standalone\configuration\application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
17:16:53,801 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory SERVER_PATH\wildfly-18.0.1.Final\standalone\deployments
17:16:53,806 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "myApplication.war" (runtime-name: "myApplication.war")
17:16:53,815 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
17:16:54,236 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.3.0.Final (Apache CXF 3.3.3) 
17:16:55,095 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry toolbox.jar in SERVER_PATH/wildfly-18.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/myApplication.war/WEB-INF/lib/iText-2.0.8.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
17:16:55,095 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry bcmail-jdk14-138.jar in SERVER_PATH/wildfly-18.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/myApplication.war/WEB-INF/lib/iText-2.0.8.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
17:16:55,095 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry bcprov-jdk14-138.jar in SERVER_PATH/wildfly-18.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/myApplication.war/WEB-INF/lib/iText-2.0.8.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
17:16:55,456 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for datasource1
17:16:55,456 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for datasource2

...
other persistence.xml reading
...


17:16:56,949 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-5) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Infinity Minus ONE +2' 9.4.16.Final
17:16:57,047 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
17:16:57,239 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
17:16:57,508 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (version 6.4)
17:16:57,538 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = myApplication.war_com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver_6_4
17:16:57,795 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "myApplication.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.naming.context.java.datasource1",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.datasource2",
        
        ...
        other required services not installed
        ...
        
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"myApplication.war#datasource1\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.datasource1]",
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"myApplication.war#datasource2\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.datasource2]"
        
        ...
        other missing dependencies
        ...
        
    ]
}
17:16:57,802 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "myApplication.war" (runtime-name : "myApplication.war")
17:16:57,806 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.naming.context.java.dbDB1 (missing) dependents: [service jboss.persistenceunit."myApplication.war#datasource1", service jboss.persistenceunit."myApplication.war#datasource1".__FIRST_PHASE__] 
      service jboss.naming.context.java.dbDB2 (missing) dependents: [service jboss.persistenceunit."myApplication.war#datasource2".__FIRST_PHASE__, service jboss.persistenceunit."myApplication.war#datasource2"] 
      
      ...
      other missing dependencies
      ...
      
      
      

WFLYCTL0448: 350 additional services are down due to their dependencies being missing or failed
17:16:57,835 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
17:16:57,838 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
17:16:57,839 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
17:16:57,839 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 18.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 10.0.3.Final) started (with errors) in 12801ms - Started 1754 of 2359 services (389 services failed or missing dependencies, 470 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Comment: 1. Remove the data-source, install from fresh installation. 2 Try with another driver and version.

Comment: @FranciscoMelojunior I've tried both your solutions but nothing changes